# Array of pointers to structs in a pointer to a struct

Tags: c, memory-management, tree

The code below attempts to initialise a node and in doing so, dynamically initialise an array of pointers to child nodes. However, I get a `Segmentation fault: 11` when I try to access the children. I realise that I should not be getting any meaningful values (i.e. it will just be junk in memory) but I don't know why I'm getting the segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INIT_SIZE 10

typedef struct node_t node_t;

struct node_t {
  char *word;
  node_t **children;
  int arr_len;
};

void set_array_vals(node_t *root);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char *word = "hello";

    node_t *root = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    assert(root);

    root->children = malloc(sizeof(node_t *) * INIT_SIZE);
    assert(root->children);
    root->arr_len = INIT_SIZE;

    root->word = malloc((sizeof(char)) * (strlen(word) + 1));
    assert(root->word);
    strcpy(root->word, word);

    set_array_vals(root);
    printf("Arr len: %d\n", root->arr_len);

    return 0;
}

void set_array_vals(node_t *root) {
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<root->arr_len; i++) {
        node_t *this_node = root->children[i];
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, this_node->arr_len);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have allocated memory for the array that holds the pointers to the children, but you haven't actually allocated memory for the children.

Comment: Count the number of `malloc(sizeof(node_t))` you have and the number of nodes you are expecting.

Comment: Ah, you're right. So from here, I should malloc a node to each array position (pointer to node) to allocate the memory for the children?

Comment: exactly, you can do in the loop in `set_array_vals` itself.

Comment: Please do not change the question in regard of answers. This makes the answers look wrong. Could you please rollback to revision 1?

Comment: Despite being a problem in the original code posted here it wasn't the actual problem (it was a typo), should I still roll it back? Excuse my inexperience here.

Comment: @Kyle If it's not in your actual code, then you don't need to revert your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `set_array_vals` you get the pointers from the "array" `root->children`, but that array is not initialized, and the pointers will be *indeterminate* and seemingly random. Dereferencing those pointers leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also, you seem to forget that array indexes start at *zero*. And once you make all pointers in the `root->children` array valid, you have to remember to initialize the structures they point to as well, otherwise the value of `this_node->arr_len` will be indeterminate.

Comment: Actually, `set_array_vals` is doing nothing as it uses a local variable. Ah...yes. It uses uninitialized dereferenced memory.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by others, firstly `children` is of `node_t **` type & you have allocated memory only for `root->children` not for `root->children[row]`. Allocate memory dynamically for `root->children[row]` & assign some values. It may looks like

```
 root->arr_len = INIT_SIZE;
 for(int row = 0; row < root->arr_len ;row++) {
         root->children[row] = malloc(sizeof(node_t));/* allocate memory for each children */
         root->children[row]->arr_len = row + 99;/* ?? assign some values into member of struct so that you can print in
                                                                            set_array_vals & verify  */
            }
```

And  in `set_array_vals()` start printing from `i=0` as above you allocated memory from `root->children[0]` to `root->children[9]` & accessing beyond size may results in undefined behavior.

```
void set_array_vals(node_t *root) {
        for (int i = 0; i < root->arr_len; i++) { /* start printing from i=0 , not i=1 */
                #if 0
                node_t *this_node = root->children[i]; /* no need of any temporary pointer */
                printf("%d: %d\n", i, this_node->arr_len);
                #endif
                printf("%d: %d\n", i, root->children[i]->arr_len);
        }
}
```